# Finding leaf directories in linux

Tags: shell, unix, find, posix

```
find . -type d  -links 2
```

seems not to be working, and produces empty output, maybe because I'm trying to do it on a NTFS formate disc? On my home volume it works.

Also, funnily enough it seems all kinds of dirs just output `.` to `ls -dA` and `find . -type d -links 1` outputs all dirs.

Is NTFS just broken on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command `find . -type d  -links 2` looks for directories that have two hard links.

On Windows, [according to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a hard link is created with the CreateHardLink function.  Further, [according to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that function does **not** support directories, only files:

> Establishes a hard link between an existing file and a new file. This
>   function is only supported on the NTFS file system, and only for
>   files, not directories.

In other words, the reason that `find . -type d -links 2` returns no directories on NTFS  is that there are no hard-linked directories on NTFS.  If you want hard-linked directories, you need a different file system.

Consequently, it is not a surprise that, if one attempts to hard link directories on an NTFS file system, `ln` will report an error:

```
$ ln dir1 dir2
ln: ‘dir1’: hard link not allowed for directory
```

NTFS does support hard-linked files and `find . -type f -links 2` will provide you with a list of files with two links.

Comment: I was under the misconception that '.' and '..' were hardlinks and was trying to count them to show leaf subdirs... instead of whatever they are.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a nasty alternative in case someone has the same problem for a NTFS partition in linux:

find . -type d -exec sh -c 'test $(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l) -eq 1' {} \; -exec whatever_you_want_here {} \;

it works out because in a leaf dir the only directory returned by that is '.'